# How to save 2 fields in 2 different tables with this structure? - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I think I'm doing right because when I submit info in the form it just save `nif` in `table1`, but not `nif_table2` in `table2`.

The 2 tables have a relation thanks to their ID_tableX, there aren't any field more.

I don't see any error so I think the main problem is in the models, did you see anything?

##### `EnviarCurriculum.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EnviarCurriculum extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table1';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_table1';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nif'
    ];

    public function enviarcurriculumpreguntas()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(EnviarCurriculumPreguntas::class);
    }
}
```

##### `EnviarCurriculumPreguntas.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class EnviarCurriculumPreguntas extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'table2';

    protected $primaryKey = 'ID_table2';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nif_table2'
    ];
}
```

##### `EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\Configuracion;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum()]);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());
    }
}
```

##### `enviar_curriculum.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>

    <form action="{{ route("store") }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        
        <input type="text" name="nif" id="nif">

        <input type="text" name="nif_table2" id="nif_table2">

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enviar"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just must put

> EnviarCurriculumPreguntas::create($request->validated());

in `EnviarCurriculumController.php`

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\enviarCurriculum;

use App\EnviarCurriculum;
use App\EnviarCurriculumPreguntas;
use App\Configuracion;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreEnviarCurriculumPost;

class EnviarCurriculumController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $configuraciones = Configuracion::orderBy('valor')->get();

        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum(), 'configuraciones' => $configuraciones]);
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $configuraciones = Configuracion::orderBy('valor')->get();

        return view('enviar_curriculum', ['EnviarCurriculum' => new EnviarCurriculum(), 'configuraciones' => $configuraciones]);
    }

    public function store(StoreEnviarCurriculumPost $request)
    {
        EnviarCurriculum::create($request->validated());
        EnviarCurriculumPreguntas::create($request->validated());

        return back()->with('status', '¡Curriculum creado con éxito!');
    }
}
```

I'm a pro e.e